# RDP, how to hide local Taskbar when an always-on-top window exists

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

When I open Remote Desktop Connection window full-screen, if there is an always-on-top window such as a video player, the local Taskbar persists, so I cannot see the remote Taskbar.

Is there anyway to make the local Taskbar hidden whether there is an always-on-top window exists or not? I usually have a small video player window all the time (always-on-top), even when using remote desktop.

---

Update

With the latest version of RDP, it no longer happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local taskbar visible during remote desktop fullscreen](https://superuser.com/questions/1243000/local-taskbar-visible-during-remote-desktop-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible with the help of a 3rd party RDP client which is able to display both taskbars (local and remote) at the same time. I am using such a client, it's called [ASG-Remote Desktop](http://www.visionapp.com/germany/solutions/asg-remote-desktop.html) (formerly visionapp Remote Desktop). The local taskbar is visible at its usual place, and the remote taskbar can stay above it.

Here is an example, see screenshot: the local explorer (Windows 10) is pinned "on top" like your video player and won't disappear when you work within the RDP session on the Windows 7 computer (see remote explorer).

BTW ASG-Remote Desktop is no freeware, but it's possible to get a license for a maximum of three simultanous used connections for free.

Having both taskbars, local and remote, visible all the time is very convenient. E.g., I can check my local emails without hiding the local desktop. Switching between different open remote sessions is very easy, too. If something will be displayed only on my local taskbar I notice it immediately, e.g. a temperature warning. The only drawback is that from now on two taskbars are visible within a remote session. Perhaps it would be a good idea to use different colors for the taskbars...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

How-to-fix-it:
Bring up the task manager on the local computer, right-click "Windows Explorer" and select "Restart".

I re-opened the RDP session and now the Fullscreen worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution how to hide local Taskbar when RDP to a remote desktop

- Launch Task Manager
- Right-click "Windows Explorer"
- Select "Restart"

It works on windows 7, 8 and 10

Answer (score 0):

For me, the root cause of the issue was an old version of Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client that apparently forced the taskbar to be on top of other windows. After updating it to version 4.5.01044, the issue has gone.

Comment: This is an old post, but I just found out that it is no longer so. I think Microsoft has updated the RDP application or something.